# CSS : Media queries delayed

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a bug on my website and I suspect a problem with media queries.
Some styles are applied as following :

```
.main {
      border:1px solid black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
   .main {
      border:1px solid red;
   }
}
```

(Of course, these are just examples a my styles are more complex.)

When I open directly my webpage with a width below 350px, I can see the original CSS rule (`border:1px solid black;`) during 1s before the media query applies (`border:1px solid red;`). It's more noticeable on an old device (CPU's performance ?) .

But, when I change the browser's width to below 350px, the media query applies smoothly.

Question : how can I fix it ?

Comment: It maybe the case of internet issue or perfomance. Kindly prepare demo on jsfiddle or codepen or something like that. So that we can experience the same.

Comment: @Sagar I'm not sure about Internet issue : the css is not loaded by chunks. For me it's more CPU but not sure ...

Comment: having the same issue on an iPhone

Comment: Having same issues only on iPhone :-/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the media query minimum and maximum width together?

Please check the below,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 350px) and (min-width: 0px) 
{
  Your Styles
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.main {
      border:1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 350px) {
   .main {
      border:1px solid black;
   }
}
```